# How to set PATH variable using content in file?

Tags: windows, path, redirection

I know I can set the PATH variable in Windows using e.g.

```
set path="%path%;c:\directoryPath"
```

or, permanently with `setx` using:

```
setx path "%path%;c:\directoryPath"
```

However, how can I set this using the input from a file, using command redirection?
Say, I have a file `mypaths.txt` that contains my complete path setting:

```
C:\Program Files\myappA;C:\Program Files\myappB;...
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
set path= < mypaths.txt
```

But this doesn't work. So how to do this correctly?

Comment: Can you read the file contents into a variable and then pass that as the argument?

Comment: @Raystafarian  mybatchfile %var%    <--- %var% could be the filename, or with the help of `<afile set/p var=`,  var can be the contents of a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I set the PATH variable using the contents of a file?

You can do this using `set /p ...` or `setx ... /f ...`

---

#### `set /p ...` solution

```
set /p PATH=<mypaths.txt
```

Notes:

- Do **not** put any spaces around `=<`.
- Syntax `set /p variable=[promptString]`
- The `/p` switch allows you to set a variable equal to a line of input entered by the user (which can be redirected to come from a file).
- The Prompt string can be empty.

---

#### `setx ... /f ...` solution

```
setx PATH /f mypaths.txt
```

Notes:

- `/f FileName` The file that you want to read.
- `/f` supports the parsing of plain text files only, (with CR/LF line endings).

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [setx](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) - Set environment variables permanently, SETX can be used to set Environment Variables for the machine (HKLM) or currently logged on user (HKCU).